# How to respond with coffee script

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, ujs

How can I respond with coffee flavoured JS?

```
def new
  respond_with { |format| format.js }
end

# new.js.coffee.erb
$('#blah_' + @blah.id).something ->
  etc...
```

This breaks, though: `missing template`. I need to choose between coffee or `erb`, but I want both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you suffix your template with `.js.coffee` you'll get both ERB and CoffeeScript capabilities.

This is highly confusing because most templates you define which pre-processors you want your templates to run through by adding extensions. See this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/rails/coffee-rails/issues/36

Answer (score 3):

Your template should be named **.js.coffee**.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to choose between coffee or js, since coffee compiles to js.